# In Matlab, how to direct to a folder that sits one folder behind home directory?

Tags: matlab

This command will set the directory to a folder named 'test', contained within the folder where the .m script with the line below exists.

```
dir_test = 'test'; %Set directory
```

How can I direct to a folder sitting one directory behind the "home" folder?

Comment: No, that directory is relative to the **current directory**, which is not necessarily (and often isn't) the directory where the M-file lives. Are you asking how to go up one directory? As in `../test`?

Comment: Yes, wondering how to go up one or more directories

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
cd ..
```

it will take you one directory behind wherever you are.

Comment: yep, I was overthinking things. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can accept this as an answer.